# while executing the npm install, it is showing error shasum check failed

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, gulp

i am trying to execute npm install in repository but it is showing this error
few days back it was working fine but today m getting this error

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-70-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/node" "/home/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-21611-583a4ffd/registry.npmjs.org/has-gulplog/-/has-gulplog-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 6414#82913697da51590397dafb12f22967811ce
npm ERR! Actual:   6414c82913697da51590397dafb12f22967811ce
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/has-gulplog/-/has-gulplog-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/userName/repository/repositoryName/npm-debug.log
```

and i think ny command with npm is also not working,
i don't want to upgrade my nodejs and npm

Comment: By the way your node and npm versions are quite old. You’ll probably find fewer issues on a recent version (if it works on this project)

Comment: @fregante i know,about my project is developed on this version and am not allowed to upgrade,thats why i already mentioned -i don't want to upgrade my versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your NPM cache. (`npm cache clean`)

The expected checksum having a `#` in it is indicative of 1-bit data corruption somewhere (bad memory? bad hard drive?) since the binary value for a `#` is `0b00100011` and for the correct character `c` it is `0b01100011` (an one-bit difference).